# Laravel Import Excel into DB using Maatwebsite\Excel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to use the Maatwebsite\Excel package to let users import a csv or excel file and it get imported into the DB. Also i am storing my excel sheet into the public/uploads folder and after  that I am executing the Export function. You can check this logic into my controller so far my file goes into the public/uploads folder.

I keep getting the error this error .

**Undefined array key 1**
[image: Please check the error image]

Also, I am giving my excel sheet screenshot please check this as well.

[image]

**Controller**

```
public function uploadCsvQuizFile(Request $request){

        $file = $request->uploading_file;


        //dd($file);
        //Display File Name
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        echo '<br>';
        //Display File Extension
        echo 'File Extension: '.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        echo '<br>';
        //Display File Real Path
        echo 'File Real Path: '.$file->getRealPath();
        echo '<br>';
        //Display File Size
        echo 'File Size: '.$file->getSize();
        //Display File Mime Type
        echo 'File Mime Type: '.$file->getMimeType();
        //Move Uploaded File
        $destinationPath = public_path().'\uploads';
        $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());

        $data = Excel::import(new QuizImport,public_path('\uploads\file.xlsx'));

        if($data){
            return redirect()->back()->with('success','Quiz Updated Successfully');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('error','Something Went Wrong');
        }

    }
```

**Import Class**

```
<?php    
    namespace App\Imports;
    
    use App\Models\QuizModel;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
    
    
    class QuizImport implements ToModel
    {
        /**
        * @param array $row
        *
        * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
        */
        public function model(array $row)
        {
    
            return new QuizModel([
                'quiz_id' => $row[0],
                'question_title' => $row[1],
                'option_a' => $row[2],
                'option_b' => $row[3],
                'option_c' => $row[4],
                'option_d' => $row[5],
                'correct_option' => $row[6],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class QuizModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'unit_quiz_questions';
    protected $fillable = ['question_id','quiz_id','question_title','option_a','option_b','option_c','option_d','correct_option','created_at','updated_at'];
}
```

Comment: can you open the uploaded file in the uploads directory with excel?

Comment: yes i can open that file as well.

Comment: Any Idea what I am doing wrong in this code its more then 4 hours I am stuck. @Snapey

Comment: Try to dd($row); in your import class to see what you're actually getting for data.

Comment: `
array:8 [▼
  0 => "quiz_id1"
  1 => "question1"
  2 => "option_a1"
  3 => "option_b1"
  4 => "option_c1"
  5 => "option_d1"
  6 => "correct_option1"
  7 => null
]


`

i am getting this after dd($row)  @ImJT

Comment: Also how can i exclude these for not inserting into database 
**quiz_id1  , question1  , option_a1,  option_a1,  option_b1,  option_b1,  option_d1  and correct_option**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726778/how-to-skip-first-row-when-importing-file

Comment: You need to skip over the headers using something like this ^

Comment: Maybe it fails on the last line not the first?  If the column A contains a value but the others don't.  Try adding null coalesce operator to each field; 'question_title' => $row[1] ?? null;   Also https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#skipping-rows

Comment: You have to try this:: return new QuizModel([
                'quiz_id' => $row['quiz_id'],
                'question_title' => $row['question_title'],
                'option_a' => $row['option_a'],
                'option_b' => $row['option_b'],     
                'option_c' => $row['option_c'],
                'option_d' => $row['option_d'],
                'correct_option' => $row['correct_option'],
            ]);